# How to handle crash in Windows 8 metro app in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, microsoft-metro

Is there a "standard" way to hand crash in Metro app? How to create the mini-dump file? Is the logging supposed to be file based?

Please give some advice or some posts/blogs.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle an app crash is as simple as let the application crash.

The error report will be automatically generated and later available in the store for you to analyze the possible causes that led to the problem. More details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/27/improving-apps-with-quality-reports.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for that link. Do you know if all crashes are sent through to the Windows Store dashboard (per that article), or are they sent only if CEIP is turned on? See my [SO question on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224661/windows-store-app-crashes-quality-reports-and-ceip).