# Windows Store app crashes, quality reports, and CEIP

Tags: c#, crash, windows-8, crash-reports, windows-store-apps

Microsoft's Antoine Leblond [discusses here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/27/improving-apps-with-quality-reports.aspx) how the Windows Store dashboard shows app crashes, which is nice.

Separately, Microsoft has [an article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618322.aspx) that talks about their Windows Customer Experience Improvement (CEIP) system, noting that CEIP is turned off by default in Windows 8. However, the article also says this:

> When Windows 8 is installed and the computer is started for the first
>   time, the Initial Configuration Tasks dialog box appears. Accepting
>   the default recommendations for Initial Configuration Tasks turns on
>   the Customer Experience Improvement Program

That to me indicates that most users will probably accept the default and CEIP will be turned on in most people's installs.

So my main question is: **Are the quality reports in the Windows Store dashboard done through CEIP, or is CEIP bypassed and the reports are always sent for Windows Store apps?**

Kind of related, do these quality reports work and send stack traces for C# apps as well as C++ apps?

Comment: You could also use BugSense to get real-time crash reports http://www.bugsense.com/docs/windows8. Disclaimer: I am a founder.

Comment: Interesting. How does BugSense work? Does it work around this [major issue with UnhandledException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344357/unhandled-exception-handler-not-called-for-metro-winrt-ui-async-void-event-han)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this article might be able to give an answer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967787.aspx

If I am not mistaken, the quality reports belong to the **analytics data collection**, which according to the article is always being gathered no matter if CEIP is enabled or not.

Comment: No, I don't think that's correct. The article says about telemetry, "Telemetry refers to the data we collect about your app ... how long it has been running, and whether it has experienced an error such as crashed..." and "Even if you enable telemetry data collection for your apps, we only collect telemetry data from customers who have opted in to the Customer Experience Improvement Program (CEIP)."

Comment: You should specify what you mean by "quality report" - reports while the application is running (telemetry) or reviews, ratings, number of downloads etc. in the Windows Store (analytics). Omho both can be viewed as quality reports. :)